# How would i use tailwind and a function in my classname property?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am very new to react and tailwind. Here is what i am trying to accomplish in pseudo code:

```
<Component className={aFunction(), 'some-tailwind-code'}></Component>
```

How would i accomplish this?

ive been trying to search around the internet but cant find anything because i cant word my question correctly.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, kindly clear your question what you want to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to accomplish what you want you can use [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) package to concatenate classNames.

In your code, it would be :

```
<Component className={clsx(aFunction(), 'some-tailwind-code')}></Component>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use clsx

`npm install --save clsx`

Import to your project
`import clsx from  'clsx';`

```react
<Component className={ clsx(aFunction(), 'some-tailwind-code')}></Component>
```